# Should there be two tags for the same thing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I found a tag named [replication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication) and another called [dna-replication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dna-replication). Shouldn't they be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have synonymized [replication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication) with [dna-replication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dna-replication) (master).

Comment: Just a thought: perhaps a full merge of these 2 tags would be better (after examining all `replication` tagged questions of course). My reasoning is because a `replication` tag could be useful to instead apply to experimental replication....(Though, perhaps such a tag should just be `experimental-replication`, and the `replication` tag just be dropped?) I did not check to see if such questions already existed. I do know, however, that the `experimental-design` tag would cover the concept of experimental replication.  Anyway, 'replication' is fairly ambiguous and I'm just thinking out loud...